# how to add footer in message reply

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to add a footer with message.author.tag and message.author.displayAvatarURL by message reply but it doesn't work "Unexpected template string"

```js
if (!args.length)
  return message.channel.send({
    embed: {
      color: "BLUE",
      title: "Weather",
      timestamp: new Date(),
      description:
        "See the temperature of a city\n\n" +
        "**Ex:**\n" +
        "`.weather` `New York`\n\n" +
        ":question:**How work?**\n" +
        "`.weather` `name of city`",
      footer: {
        text: `${message.author.tag}`, `${message.author.displayAvatarURL}`
      },
   },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [`MessageEmbedFooter#iconURL`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageEmbedFooter) and `MessageEmbedFooter#text` property:

```js
footer: { 
  text: message.author.tag, 
  iconURL: message.author.displayAvatarURL(),
}
```

---

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: there's no way to leave a text before and after showing the message.author.tag, right?
ex: text: 'command 123' message.author.tag,

Comment: Not that I know of, no.